# Ruby's Gemfile equivalent

Tags: android, iphone, bundle, equivalent, gemfile

I have a simple question. Is there an equivalent to Ruby on Rail's Gemfile for iPhone development and/or Android development?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iOS you can use Cocoapods
http://cocoapods.org/

Answer (score 1):

Apache Maven for Javas jar dependencies.